# UICollectionView scroll action control with pagingEnabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have square sized `UIView`(width: 320, height:320) to play videos within `UICollectionView` and horizontal scroll in my project. This collection view's `pagingEnbled` set as YES.

[image]

My issue is that when a user scroll to the next video, it automatically plays the next video because I set to play video in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. However, what I want to do is to wait to play the video until the user finish scrolling and play video after the next cell is fully visible. Also, since the video in previous cell is still playing because the content should be played. All in all, I want to prevent the collection view from setting visible cell while scrolling. I think I need to achieve this one with `UIScrollView` contentOffset. But I do not know how to do this. It would be super helpful if you guys give me a hint for this problem. Thanks!

Comment: instead of setting play in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, set play in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. It will allow user to select and then play.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
```

Once the drag is finished you can play the video contained in the visible cell maybe using this UICollectionView method

```
- (NSArray *)indexPathsForVisibleItems
```

Comment: Thanks. But that is not what I want. I think I should be more clear for this issue. What I want to do is that play the video in the previous cell and stop the video in next cell while a user scroll to the next cell. So, I think that I need to reset the scrolling values not just visible cell. I will edit my question

Comment: Probably is not what you want but for sure is what you asked :)